# SPFx Yeoman generates wrong package versions

Tags: spfx, npm, yeoman-generator

In the past I have generated SPFx projects successfully using @microsoft/generator-sharepoint yeoman generator, but now it is not giving me the same versions for the SPFx packages. I discovered it was using the wrong versions after not being able to find MSGraphClientFactory in the project context.

**Below is the package.json dependencies for the project with old versions**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
  }
```

**Below is the package.json dependencies for the project with correct versions**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^1.12.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.10.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.32",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/simplebar": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "6.189.2",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

*Notice that the versions should be 1.10.0 but they are being set to ~1.4.0.*

**Below is the result I get after running npm ls -g --depth=0**

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
+-- @pnp/office365-cli@2.10.0
+-- gulp@4.0.2
`-- yo@3.1.1
```

I tried running npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g as well as updating the generator through Yeoman, but no luck.

I have not changed any of my choices when creating the project. I choose SP Online and I use React as the framework.

If anyone can help me get the correct package versions downloading it would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by running:

```
npm cache clear --force
```